# Addon for placing pinpoints on an image?

Tags: image

I'm looking to do something similar to the pink pinpoints seen on the screenshots here: http://ee-garage.com/nsm-live-look

I want the client to be able to add pins at a certain point on the image and optionally add some content to that pin.

I tried looking through Devot-ee, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I built Pointee a while back, should cover a fair amount of what you need.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pointee

Looking forward to the pull requests :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is not a publicly released add-on that allows you to create anything like that.

Comment: ...looks like I might have to build one myself! Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: You might contact ObjectiveHTML he has a new photo add-on coming out soon that has a ton of photo customization features already bundled and I assume an API that you can access

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't seen this has just been released:

http://www.devdemon.com/entry_mapper/

I have just started using it on a site right now and is so far working great.